# Access Forms: Passing custom properties to Chart

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am building a form that is supposed to show some histograms that aggregate some queries. Since access has no native support for histogram charts, the SQL query set as the data source for each chart is relatively verbose and repetitive. The idea is to draw all corners of each column in the histogram manually in a xy-plot. Currently I achieve this by the following query:

```
select
    bin(field,50,-1000,1000) - 25 AS bin,
    1 as cnt,
    3 as ord
FROM tab
GROUP BY bin(field,50,-1000,1000) - 25

union all

select
    bin(field,50,-1000,1000) - 25 AS bin,
    Count(*) AS cnt,
    4 as ord
FROM tab
GROUP BY bin(field,50,-1000,1000) - 25

union all

select
    bin(field,50,-1000,1000) + 25 AS bin,
    Count(*) AS cnt,
    1 as ord
FROM tab
GROUP BY bin(field,50,-1000,1000) + 25

union all 

select
    bin(field,100,-2000,2000) + 500 AS bin,
    1 as cnt,
    2 as ord
FROM tab
GROUP BY bin(field,50,-1000,1000) + 25

order by bin, ord
```

where bin is a VBA function that chooses the bin depending on the bin width and boundaries. You may notice that the binning configuration occurs eight times in this query.

I would like to add custom properties to the chart control that can be referred to in the query. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

**Remark:** You might suggest that I could use other controls to configure the binning. However, I have many of these charts, and I would like to easily add new ones with individual binning. If I had other controls for the binning, I would have to copie this as well and adjust the references to them in the SQL, which I suppose not to amount to less work.

Comment: What do you mean with _custom properties_? There's the _tag_ property that you can use for anything you want.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Ah, that sounds like the first half of the solution. How, is there a possibility to refer to the properties of the *current* chart control, without explicitly knowing its name? Something like `Me.Properties("Tag")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as the *current chart*, since a form can contain many charts. You can, however, identify all charts on a form, and do a specific operation with them:

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls 'Or Forms!SomeForm.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is Access.ObjectFrame 'OLE object, can be chart
        If ctl.OLEClass = "Microsoft Graph Chart"
            'Do stuff with the ctl.Tag property
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Who "owns" a query? What I am trying to ask: Given a control that has an SQL query as its data source: Is it possible to access properties of that control from within its associated SQL w/o knowing the name of that control?

Comment: I just gave you a way to iterate through _all_ controls on a form. You can do the same for reports. You can refer to the control by using the `ctl` object in my example

Comment: I understand your approach. However, I would have liked to achieve this without rebuilding the entire query in VBA based on the Tag property.

Comment: Well... you're asking a lot of different things, most of which are impossible. You can't refer to an unknown control from a query

Comment: Well, to me it is not clear that this control is unknown, but it is the control the query is associated to.

Comment: A query has no conception of which control it's associated to. Queries are separate from the GUI/VBA portion of Access.